# Changing the color of text with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a program where I use a function to change the color of pre-written text using an array and a for loop, depending on what the user inputs when prompted.  Here is my code:

```js
// <Student Name> <Student ID> comment must be here.

// This function will change the color of the text to the name of the color you give it.
function changeColor(colorText) {
  var text = document.getElementById("colorpar");
  text.innerHTML = "<font color=\"" + colorText + "\">The color is " + colorText + ".</font>";
}


// Declare, create, and put values into your color array here
var colors = new Array(5);

colors[0] = "green";
colors[1] = "blue";
colors[2] = "yellow";
colors[3] = "orange";
colors[4] = "red";


// Create a loop that runs 4 times.
// Each time it asks the user for a number between 0 and 4.
// If an invalid input is entered, the color displayed should be black.
// Otherwise display the color at that index in the array.
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  var colNumber = window.prompt("Enter a number from 0 to 4:");
  if (colNumber == 0 || colNumber == 1 || colNumber == 2 || colNumber == 3 || colNumber == 4) {
    changeColor(colors[colNumber]);
  } else {
    changeColor("black");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lab 7 Task 2</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
  <h1 id="colorpar">
  The color is black.
 </h1>

  <h1>
 </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

What happens is the text will only show once I've done all of the prompts.  It shows the proper color and text and everything, but at the start the "The color is black." doesn't show up, and nothing does until the last prompt is answered.

Note that this is for a beginner class so anything much more advanced than what I have here won't be of much help.  I did not write the function, it is there as part of the assignment.  I've been at this for hours and can't figure out the issue!

Comment: `font` tag is deprecated and is unsupported in HTML5. Do not use this. Use CSS styles instead.

Comment: This is for a class and we haven't learned any CSS.  The function was created by my professor.  The only things I've done are under the '//Declare, create, and put values into your color array here'

Comment: Of course it will always prompt you 4 times, you are looping. You should instead have a button that you should click if you want to change colors.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: `window.prompt` will return a string. you need to convert it to an integer with `parseInt` for the proceeding `if` statement to work.

Comment: @Polyov It will work because his comparison operator is `==` not `===`.

Comment: (1) You should find a new class or new teacher who teaches JS/HTML as it's written in 2016, not 2006. (2) You need to give the browser a chance to "breathe" (re-render) between color changes.

Comment: The text color is supposed to change after every time they enter a value for the prompt.  My issue is that the text does not even appear until the last prompt is answered.  It shows up correctly (eg. if 4 is entered in the last prompt window, the text will be red and say "The color is red")

Comment: I've tried waiting 30 seconds after each answer and nothing changes unfortunately.

Comment: @InitialBN The thing is, your code actually is working. If you set a breakpoint in the changeColor function using Chrome Developer Tools (or something similar), you will see the color of the text change. It could be that the browser is getting to the next iteration in the loop before it redraws the screen with the new color.

Answer (score 2):

Use SetInterval for this.

check the following code snippet

```js
function changeColor(colorText) {
  var text = document.getElementById("colorpar");
  text.innerHTML = "<font color=\"" + colorText + "\">The color is " + colorText + ".</font>";
}


// Declare, create, and put values into your color array here
var colors = new Array(5);

colors[0] = "green";
colors[1] = "blue";
colors[2] = "yellow";
colors[3] = "orange";
colors[4] = "red";


// Create a loop that runs 4 times.
// Each time it asks the user for a number between 0 and 4.
// If an invalid input is entered, the color displayed should be black.
// Otherwise display the color at that index in the array.
var x = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if (x == 4) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
  var colNumber = window.prompt("Enter a number from 0 to 4:");
  if (colNumber == 0 || colNumber == 1 || colNumber == 2 || colNumber == 3 || colNumber == 4) {
    setTimeout(changeColor(colors[colNumber]), 1000);

  } else {
    changeColor("black");
  }
  x++;
}, 100);
```

```html
<body bgcolor="white">
  <h1 id="colorpar">
    The color is black.
</h1>

  <h1>
</h1>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This will work, but some explanation as to why it solves the problem would be nice.

Comment: That worked pretty well!  The only issue is that we haven't learned anything like that, and the assignment is to use what we've learned in class which is just for/while loops and arrays.  If I used this I likely wouldn't get marks.

Comment: It works well with setInterval because, as you are looping through and adding a color to the element ,the time between prompt and adding a color is not much ,so it could not show whats happening.So,setinterval helps us to see the colors attached to the element with an interval mentioned

Comment: I dont think it can be solved the way you mentioned only for loops.

Comment: @InitialBN I agree with Geeky. If you have to use a prompt to enter the data then there's no other solution. If you can trigger the change with an input on the page and a button, then there are other solutions. Sounds like a poorly thought-out question from a teacher who hasn't tried to do it himself. I'm pretty sure you don't need the extra setTimeout though.

Comment: If it is of any help ...consider accepting the answer